# TypeError: object of type 'IMapIterator' has no len() for pool.imap

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I am getting following error:

```
df_OP = pd.DataFrame([excel_write_data[idx].__dict__ for idx in range(0, 
len(excel_write_data))])

TypeError: object of type 'IMapIterator' has no len().
```

I am using imap for parrallel processing but I am getting above error

```
excel_write_data = pool.imap(pre_process, excel_read_data)
```

How can i overcome this error . can any one help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `IMapIterator` is an iterable, but you need something that acts like a list (has a `len()`). So, make it a list:

```
excel_write_data = list(pool.imap(pre_process, excel_read_data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. it really helped me,

Comment: @SayliJawale: You're welcome! You can upvote my answer and accept it if it solved your issue.